# Can't make a vertex line from the top end of the apple and the bottom end

Tags: modeling, vertices

I am a beginner at using Blender, and trying to make an apple. But I can't make the vertex line from the top to the bottom of the apple connect, I tried to connect it by pressing a line and then pressing another line to connect it but it can't connect and the vertex line disappears.

This is what I tried to do (video tutorial where the vertex line can connect from the top end to the bottom end of the apple) :

[image]

This is what I do :

[image]

Comment: Could you share your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: You didnt share link to tutorial, but select edge loop can be done by Shift+Alt+RightClick (if you use right click select setup) by clicking on edge between two vertices.

Comment: ...or just Alt-LeftClick on an edge between two of the vertices to select the loop if you're using the default left-click select layout. (Don't know why folks say you need to use Shift as well unless you're adding to a selection of multiple loops!)

Comment: @JohnEason ... right :) but in this case you would have to select opposite edge loop as well so Shift is used in this scenario.

Comment: @vklidu True in this case. It's just that everyone seems to think that you always need to use Shift and Alt! I've seen that so many times in tutorials where it isn't necessary.

Comment: @JohnEason ... I'm user from 2000, probably it was a shortcut of older versions ... just guessing :)

Comment: Ah. Could be. I think I used 2.79 once before 2.8 appeared! :^)

Comment: Thank you to all of you! sorry I'm late replying. I found another way by pressing the vertex point then the ctrl key until pressing another vertex point and it worked! Thank you to everyone who took the time to help!